# How to add snippet to Visual Studio Code for multiple languages?

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets

I have couple of snippets that shared between `js`, `jsx` and `html` files. Now I have the same snippet code in 3 files. Is it possible to create snippet and specify to what files/types it should be applicable?

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/13182

Comment: Specifically https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/13182#issuecomment-355301995

Answer (score 19):

Hit `cmd + p` to access the command bar, then type 'snippets' and select **Preferences: Configure User Snippets**, then **New Global Snippets file**. Once you name your file, it will create a global snippets file where you can define snippets that are accessible in any language defined on the `scope` property.

```
"Div Tag": {
  "scope": "javascript,javascriptreact,html",
  "prefix": "div",
  "body": "<div>$1</div>",
  "description": "Create a div tag"
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

Fixed the scope property with the correct language identifiers in response to the comments.

Comment: The file terminations `js,jsx` did not work in my case. Instead I used `"scope": "javascript,javascriptreact"` to get the snippets to work in .js and .jsx files.
Check this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/55653650/8182578