# VSCode user snippet doesn't works inside jsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code

I have a some snippet:

```
"JSON stringify": {
        "prefix": "jst",
        "body": [
            "<pre>{JSON.stringify($1, null, 2)}</pre>"
        ]
    },
```

and it works inside js scope, but when I'm trying to do same trick inside jsx render - it dont want to be working.

How to tell my VSCode, that I want to do same things inside jsx?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Putting that snippet into your global snippets file should work.

`Gear Icon`/`User Snippets`/ `myGlobalSnippets.code-snippets`

Answer (score 71):

Maybe adding "scope" to your snippet:

```
"scope": "javascript,typescript,javascriptreact,typescriptreact",
```

javascriptreact ---> jsx files

It should be like this...

```
"JSON stringify": {
  "scope": "javascript,typescript,javascriptreact",
  "prefix": "jst",
  "body": [
    "<pre>{JSON.stringify($1, null, 2)}</pre>"
  ]
},
```

*Note:* The snippet should be a [New Global Snippet file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_create-your-own-snippets).

**scope breakdown:**

- javascript => .js
- typescript => .ts
- javascriptreact => .jsx
- typescriptreact => .tsx

Comment: ...and `typescriptreact` for `.tsx` files.

Comment: this is the real solution by changing scope values worked as expected

Answer (score 3):

In vscode Press the ***gear*** button then choose ***User Snippets*** then type ***javascriptreact*** if you are using "javascript" or ***typescriptreact*** for"typescript" then past the snippet code that you want :D

Answer (score 2):

I had to put `"scope": "javascript,jsx,jsx-attr"`. Perhaps there's a neater way but that did it for me.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like inside jsx, the type of proposed snippets is not "javascript" but "jsx":

When you go to  `File` / `Preferences` / `User snippets` you can look for the jsx format (file name `jsx.json`)

If you put your snippet in that file, it should be available inside your jsx

Answer (score 0):

just remove scope key from object, it worked for me

```
"JSON stringify": {
  "scope": "javascript,typescript,javascriptreact",
  "prefix": "jst",
  "body": [
    "<pre>{JSON.stringify($1, null, 2)}</pre>"
  ]
}
```

to

```
"JSON stringify": {
  "prefix": "jst",
  "body": [
    "<pre>{JSON.stringify($1, null, 2)}</pre>"
  ]
}
```